# No such column - Django

Tags: python, django

My goal is to let users upload files to user-specific folders.

The error I get is

```
no such column: notendur_document.user_id
```

Here is the relevant part of my `views.py` file. This is where the upload happens.

```
@login_required
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notendur.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # An empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'notendur/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

This is my `models.py` file:

```
def _upload_path(instance,filename):
    return instance.get_upload_path(filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def get_upload_path(self,filename):
        return "media/uploads/"+str(self.user.id) + "/" + '%Y.%m.%d' + filename
```

According to the relevant `.html` file, the error happens in the `documents` variable in `list()`.

register user method in `views.py`:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    args  = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

Comment: You changed your model, but forgot to migrate (or syncdb in django<1.7 without South).

Comment: I might be doing yet another thing wrong, but I get the same error. I just shut down the server, write python manage.py syncdb, and start the server again. Did I do that correctly?

Comment: Remove the database, create it again, and run syndb

Comment: It still does not work, but I have one idea. I didn't create the user from the shell. I let the user register on the website itself. Could I have done something wrong there, resulting in this error? Perhaps created the user object incorrectly?

Comment: If that is the case, I have appended my original post with the regist user code.

Comment: @user1614466 no, if there's no `user_id` column on the documents table it has nothing to do with what users you have. What database are you using?

Comment: How do you assign the user? I suspect you want to assign the user who uploads the Document, if that's what you want then you need to pass the user as an argument to the model after `form.is_valid()`, `newdoc.user = request.user` (before calling save)

Comment: I might be doing someting wrong, but it does not work on my end.

if form.is_valid():
   newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
   newdoc.user = request.user
   newdoc.save()

Comment: @user1614466 Do you have the sqlite command line utility installed? Try running `manage.py dbshell`. If it works, type `.schema notendur_document`.

Comment: Hmm when I run dbshell it says "sqlite3 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: Oh right, I'm so used to migrations I forgot that `syncdb` doesn't change the schema. You'll have to remove the database file and then run `syncdb`, as `cor` said.

Comment: I already did with the flush command. Not sure if that's the right one.

Comment: No, you have to delete the database file entirely.

Comment: HOORAY HOORAY HOORAY

ALL IS WELL, PEACE ON EARTH

It worked! cor I must apologise profusely, you tried to help me with this yesterday. But I used the flush command.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: In the future, you might want to change the models when you already have some data you don't want to lose. You'll have to alter your tables manually then, which is annoying. Consider using South for schema migrations or upgrading to Django 1.7, which has them built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass pk=True in your foreingkey 
ex. user = models.ForeignKey(User,pk=True)
this will solve the issue